# Change directory for screenshots on IPad for using Dropbox

Tags: ipad, dropbox

I would like to change the directory for the screenshots in a way that dropbox uploads it automatially. There are a lot of tutorials on MAC OS but I cannot find it for IPad. Does someone knows how to save screenshots in directory that dropbox can uploads?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the location of screenshots in iOS, they always get stored into your Photo Library. To get the into Dropbox you have to open the Dropbox ap, pick the photos you want to publish and store them into one of your Dropbox folders.